# Subset command leading to error

Tags: r, subset

I have a dataset (matchdata) in R Studio that I'm trying to subset using:

```
matchdatasub <- subset(matchdata, sample = 1)
```

"sample" is a binary variable from 0-1

The code above works but doesn't subset the data. If I run the following code:

```
matchdatasub <- subset(matchdata, sample > 0)
```

I get the error message: comparison (6) is possible only for atomic and list types.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please check `==` with `=`. `subset(matchdata, sample==1)`.  Regarding the error, I would request you to check the `str(matchdata)`.  It could be a `matrix`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also subset directly using the data frame:

```
matchdatasub <- matchdata[matchdata$sample > 0, ]
```

As @akrun mentioned, the likely root cause of your error is that you were using `sample=1` instead of `sample==1`.  Therefore, use one of the following:

```
matchdatasub <- subset(matchdata, sample==1)
```

or

```
matchdatasub <- matchdata[matchdata$sample == 1, ]
```

Comment: Thanks. Tried with both coding suggestions. First did not remove any observations (similar to original). Second removed all observations.

Comment: Please tell us the output of this: `class(matchdata$sample)` ... you could have a factor variable

Comment: How about `class(matchdata)` ?

Comment: `names(matchdata)` what does this say?  Your error is bizarre to me.

Comment: This gives me the names of the 60 variables. I have to leave for work now. Can we pick this up later. I agree that this is bizarre. I've been trying to find a solution: the command seems simple, but I can't get it to subset.

Comment: Ok. Solved--I tried some of the other binary variables. I was using incorrect capitalization in the original command. Thanks for your time. Apologies for silly mistake.